# "Use of plus() is ambiguous" error

Tags: c++, function, addition

I am trying to write a function which takes two numbers and prints out their sum.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int plus(int, int);

int main () {
 int a, b, result;
 cout << "2 numbrs";
 cin>>a>>b;
 result = plus(a,b);
 cout << result;
 return 0;
}

int plus(int a,int b) {
 int sum;
 sum = a+b;
 return sum;
}
```

and error I get:

```
use of `plus' is ambiguous
```

It´s my first C++ program and in fact I am getting blind finding an error.

Comment: We need to declare all-out war on `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @FredLarson Is curious how almost all introductory programming books/tutorials employ 

         using namespace std;
without properly explaining what that means, and when you should actually use it. (Most of the time you shouldn't)

Comment: In fact I read good explanation what is happening when using using namespace std, but I didn´t realize that can cause this problem.

Comment: @Jac08H Well that is kinda my point... If you read an "explanation" and it doesn't explain why it is a problem, then it really isn't a "good explanation".

Answer (score 22):

Either do

```
result = ::plus(a,b);
```

Or rename the function. This is a good lesson on why `using namespace std` is not considered good practice.

Comment: @Jac08H Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Jac08H There's no need to marked your question as fixed. You can just accept the appropriate answer.

Comment: `using namespace std` is considered bad practice only in header files, and it's OK in implementation files. (because it does not ooze into other modules) `using namespace std` is OK here. The real problem here is that the `plus` function is uselessly reinventing functionality, and uses a common word to do so, and this word happens to already be loaded with semantics by the Standard Library. I'd advocate to either directly use operator `+` instead of defining a function, or to define the function in the project's namespace.

Answer (score 15):

There is already a function object in the `std` [namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) called [`plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus). Because of `using namespace std;` this `std::plus` is put in the global namespace, which is also where your `plus()` is named. When you attempt to call your `plus()` the compiler can't tell whether you are referring to `std::plus` or your `plus()` because they are both in the global namespace.

You have the following options:

1. Remove `using namespace std;` (you'll then need to qualify other functions in the `std` namespace -- e.g. `std::cout`).
2. Put your `plus()` in its own namespace (say, `mine`), and call it using `mine::plus(a, b)`.
3. [Call your function with `::plus()` as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593560/3964927) (assuming you don't put it in its own namespace).
4. Rename the function so that there is no name collision.

Comment: `std::plus` is not a function, it's a function object. If you want to call it, you need to do `std::plus()(a,b)` or `std::plus{}(a,b)`.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Fixed. Thanks.